# Struts2 - session is lost after a redirect

Tags: session, jakarta-ee, redirect, struts2, httpsession

I'm working on a Java EE web application based on Struts2(say `CNG`). At a particular point, the user is redirected to a Payment Gateway (say `IM`.com) and then `IM` redirects to an Action of `CNG`. An interceptor runs before every Action checking for the session variable and it shows a value of `null` after returning from `IM`.com.

Why does this happen? How can I handle this so that my session is preserved after a redirect to another application?

EDIT:

I set my session like this in an Action:

```
SessionMap<String, Object> sessionMap = (SessionMap<String, Object>) ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

sessionMap.put("userID","1234");
```

I redirect to the `IM` application like this (on a JSP):

```
<a href="im.com/cng?q=1234">
```

`IM` , after success payment/transaction redirect to my application - `cng.com/receivePayment?p=4321`

My Interceptor that runs before every action that checks for the userID in session:

```
 public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            final ActionContext context = invocation.getInvocationContext();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)context.get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_RESPONSE);

            SessionMap<String,Object> sessionMap = (SessionMap<String,Object>)ActionContext.getContext().getSession();
            String m = invocation.getInvocationContext().getName();
            System.out.println(sessionMap.get("userID"));
            return invocation.invoke();

            }
```

When `IM` redirects back to `CNG` the interceptor runs and prints `null` i.e. I've lost my session variable..

Comment: The session itself expires when you redirect to another domain. You need to save session as cookie in browser. you can also implement the same in your action.

Comment: Post some code because it's unclear what you asking.

Comment: @RomanC just updated!

Comment: may be your action doesn't need that interceptor, unless you know that the session is empty.

Comment: @RomanC I added that interceptor to disable browser caching and subsequently session management.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I tried saving the session as a cookie. The cookie is created and stored properly (I can check for it in my Chrome Browser) but when I return to `CNG` application from `IM` the cookies cannot be fetched! They're present in the browser but the code cannot fetch it. Here's how I'm fetching it:

(in next comment)

Comment: @ParthTrivedi 

`HttpServletRequest servletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(StrutsStatics.HTTP_REQUEST);

if(servletRequest.getCookies()!=null){

    System.out.println("There are cookies -   +servletRequest.getCookies().length);

for(Cookie c : servletRequest.getCookies()) {

    if (c.getName().equals("userID")){
 System.out.println("Received cookie - "+c.getValue());
 break;
 }

    else System.out.println("can't find cookie");
       
    
 }
}
  
else {System.out.println("No cookie set yet");}  `

Comment: @ParthTrivedi Cookies work perfectly on my development environment. However, they expire when I'm trying it out on production.

Comment: @Saturnian ohh, yes I can understand, But I was also wondering to not to use cookie but saving the session in somewhere else, for example saving them in app context or as a file and reading back them on server side, because cookie may leak security attacks threats also.

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I could try out App context, yes. Although weirdly enough, the cookie approach is working really well in production all by itself, very suddenly. Sigh! I will give App context a try asap, seems cleaner. Thanks for the idea!